# lvalue required as left operand of assignment error when using C++

Tags: c++, pointers, required, lvalue

```
int main()
{

   int x[3]={4,5,6};
   int *p=x;
   p +1=p;/*compiler shows error saying 
            lvalue required as left 
             operand of assignment*/
   cout<<p 1;
   getch();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the result of `p + 1 = p` to be?

Comment: This is no C code, but C++. Change the tag and title!

Comment: `p + 1` and `p` are both single addresses in the memory, you can't assign one address to another one

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you have an assignment operator in a statement, the LHS of the operator must be something the language calls an *lvalue*. If the LHS of the operator does not evaluate to an *lvalue*, the value from the RHS cannot be assigned to the LHS.

You cannot use:

```
10 = 20;
```

since `10` does not evaluate to an *lvalue*.

You can use:

```
int i;
i = 20;
```

since `i` does evaluate to an *lvalue*.

You cannot use:

```
int i;
i + 1 = 20;
```

since `i + 1` does not evaluate to an *lvalue*.

In your case, `p + 1` does not evaluate to an *lavalue*. Hence, you cannot use

```
p + 1 = p;
```

Answer (score 6):

Put simply, an lvalue is something that can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment, typically a variable or array element.

So if you define `int *p`, then `p` is an lvalue.  `p+1`, which is a valid expression, is not an lvalue.

If you're trying to add 1 to `p`, the correct syntax is:

```
p = p + 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

To assign, you should use `p=p+1;` instead of `p+1=p;`

```
int main()
{

   int x[3]={4,5,6};
   int *p=x;
   p=p+1; /*You just needed to switch the terms around*/
   cout<<p<<endl;
   getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use an assignment operator but use it in wrong way or in wrong place, 
then you'll get this types of errors!

suppose if you type:
p+1=p; you will get the error!!

you will get the same error for this:
if(ch>='a' && **ch='z'**)
as you see can see that I i tried to assign in if() statement!!!
how silly I am!!! right??
ha ha

actually i forgot to give less then(<) sign
 if(ch>='a' && ch<='z')

and got the error!!

Answer (score 0):

It is just a typo(I guess)-

```
p+=1;
```

instead of `p +1=p;` is required .

As name suggest `lvalue` expression should be left-hand operand of the assignment operator.