# 2 different weird errors with struct assignment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Having this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test { char c; } foo;

int main (void) {

   struct Test *ar[10];
   struct Test *(*p)[] = &ar; //what type of syntax is this *(*p)[]

   *(*p+1) = &foo; // the same  (*p)[1] = &foo
   //this only works


   p[0][1] = &foo  //the same as *(*p+1) 
   ////1error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds

   (*(*p+1)+1) = &foo // the same as p[1][1] = &foo 
   ////2error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

   //HOW TO make assignment of p[1][1] = &foo   and NOT p[0][1] ??

   return 0;
}
```

I am getting 2 weird errors from trying to assign an address from struct to array of structs. I would like both error explanation and how to make the assignment (viz. code) to `p[1][1]`.

EDIT: `the same as` statements could be wrong. I just thought, they would be equally, if "normal" pointers (their type)

Comment: Ouch!  Pointers to arrays of pointers — of indeterminate size.  It's going to be hard to explain that.  It can be done, but it ain't easy.  I'm not convinced by your 'same as' comments, especially the first one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah, the first one is completely wrong, isn't it? `(*p)[0]` is the same as `*(*p)`.  No `+1` in there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler they may be wrong, if so, just say that

Comment: But I mean, why are they wrong, all of them would be right if "normal pointer" or?

Comment: @Herdsman We may not be certain.  Your code is frankly bizarre, at least to me.

Comment: Mostly I'm saying "my brain hurts" and TGIF.  The good news for you is that you're unlikely to come across anything so abstruse in the wild — people don't usually write code like that, not least because it is hard to understand and get right.  I'm going to sit on the sidelines until many hours later.  I'm hoping someone will spare me the effort of working out what's going wrong.

Comment: Might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469650/invalid-use-of-array-with-unspecified-bounds

Comment: Might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375136/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-error-when-using-c

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "normal pointer".  What's an abnormal pointer?

Comment: @DaveCosta i think this pointers have weird types, because if they have normal types (type is meant `&pointer`), it would probably work, i think at least

Comment: I would like someone very skilled and experience to answer if that hard, I really hanker for answers

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to assign an address from struct to array of structs" answering my question can make me able to answer yours

Comment: trying to assign address of `struct Test { char c; } foo;` at the beginning of file. To the pointer of array (pointer to pointer) `struct Test *ar[10]; ` but with the third pointer `***p = &ar`

Comment: you mean as the first element in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your comments line by line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test { char c; } foo;

int main (void) {

   struct Test *ar[10];
   struct Test *(*p)[] = &ar; //what type of syntax is this *(*p)[]
```

[cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/) says `struct Test *(*p)[]` means `declare p as pointer to array of pointer to struct Test`. And by the way, the array is an array of unknown/unspecified size, since there's nothing in the square brackets.

```
   *(*p+1) = &foo; // the same  (*p)[1] = &foo
   //this only works
```

You're right, and yes, it works.

```
   p[0][1] = &foo;  //the same as *(*p+1) 
   ////1error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
```

(I added your missing semicolon.) You'd usually be right, but in this case a bit of pedantry means you're not. `x[0]` isn't equivalent to `*x`, but rather `*(x + 0)`. Those are usually equivalent, but when `x` is a pointer to something of unknown size, you're not allowed to do pointer arithmetic on it.

```
   (*(*p+1)+1) = &foo; // the same as p[1][1] = &foo 
   ////2error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

(I added your missing semicolon again.) Not quite. `p[1][1]` would be `*(*(p+1)+1)`. You have your `*`s and parentheses the wrong way around.

```
   //HOW TO make assignment of p[1][1] = &foo   and NOT p[0][1] ??
```

You can't, without knowing how big the array that `*p` points to is.

```
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: So if I have determinated size say `struct Test *(*p)[10] = &ar`, then it would work?

Comment: `p[1][1]` gives me stack smashing. `*(*(p+1)+1) = &foo;` but my allocated space comes from statement ` struct Test *(*p)[10] = &ar;`,

Comment: @Herdsman Sorry, let me clarify. I meant "work" as in "valid to the compiler". That won't do what you want at runtime because you only have one array, but `p[1]` will try to access a nonexistent second array.

Comment: So how could I allocate new array to add the second needed space to achieve the above, something like `realloc(p, sizeof(&p)*2)`?

Comment: @Herdsman `struct Test *ar[2][10]; struct Test *(*p)[10] = ar;`

Comment: yes, but that is handcoded array, I meant if there is possibility to allocate new memory within an existing array, which would be in my case well suited way of that.

Comment: @Herdsman `struct Test *(*p)[10] = malloc(2 * sizeof *p);` And then you can change it later, say to 5, with `p = realloc(p, 5 * sizeof *p);`

Comment: Last question: I have added space to second array pointer: `*(*p+1) = malloc(sizeof(struct Test)*2);` space for two structs. Now I would like to make `p[0][1][1] = foo` which  I am trying to achieve like this: `*(*p+1)+1 = &foo;` (or: `(*(*p+1)+1) = &foo;` -- added only parethesis, but the same err), but that is the error: `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`, how make it?

Comment: @Herdsman `*(*p+1)+1` means `p[0][1] + 1`. You probably meant `*(*(*p+1)+1)`.

Comment: But that is dereferenced. I want to assign address `&foo` (type struct Test*). If I do `*(*(*p+1)+1) = foo` it is only shallow copy. I cannot then assign member 'c' to the foo by the pointer `p`

Comment: I need to assign a address of `&foo` in order to manipulate with the pointer and used it to assign it a member of that struct. Is it posible to somehow assign address in order to have bind to pointer `p[0][1][1]`?

Comment: @Herdsman That doesn't work for the same reason `x + 4 = 7;` doesn't work. C isn't an equation solver.

Comment: So is it possible or not? Can I assign address of `foo` to `p[0][1][1]` and manipulate with that struct? because `p` is like `struct Test ***p`, which can have 3 brackets

Comment: @Herdsman Not directly. You'd need to `malloc` at least enough room for two of them, and then store the pointer to that to `p[0][1]`.

Comment: I gave new question, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702828/how-to-initialize-a-struct-address-to-array-pointer

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> Constraints
>
> 1 One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘**pointer to complete
> object type**’’, the other expression shall have integer type, and the
> result has type ‘‘type’’.

In the left side hand of the assignment

```
p[0][1] = &foo
```

`o` is a pointer to an incomplete object type due to the declaration

```
struct Test *(*p)[] = &ar;
```

where the type `Test *[]` is incomplete type because the size of the array is unknown (unspecified). So the compiler issues an error.

In this statement

```
*(*p+1) = &foo;
```

the dereferenced pointer `p` (`*p`) used in the expression `*p + 1` is converted to pointer to the first element of the array `ar` and has the type `struct Test **`. The expression `*p + 1`  points to the second element of the array and after dereferencing *`( *p + 1 )` you get lvalue of the second element of the array that gets the address of the object foo.

In this statement

```
(*(*p+1)+1) = &foo;
```

there is used rvalue of the kind `pointer + 1`. SO you may not assign to this temporary object a value.

It looks the same as in this code snippet

```
int a[] = { 1, 2 };
int *p = &a[0];

p + 1 = &a[1];
```

Comment: So is this one wrong? `(*(*p+1)+1) = &foo;`? if so, then how should be correct?

Comment: @Herdsman It does not make sense. The expression *( *p + 1 ) yields the second element of the array. Its value was set to &foo. Now you are getting the address of the memory after the object foo and are trying to set it to &foo.