# how to initialize a struct address to array pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Having this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test { char c; } foo;

int main (void) {

   struct Test *ar[10];
   struct Test *(*p)[10] = &ar; // var 'p' is kind of type "struct Test ***p"

   *(*p+1) = malloc(sizeof(struct Test)*2); //alocated space in array p[0][1] for 2 structs

   //Now I would like to have 'foo' from above in p[0][1][1]

   // I cannot do "p[0][1][1] = foo", that is shallow copy
   // which means "p[0][1][1].c = 'c'" will have no effect
   // I need actually assign address to "&foo" to that pointer 'p'
   // something like "(*(*p+1)+1) = &foo", but that is error:
   //err: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

   // reason:
   p[0][1][1].c = 'c';
   printf("%c\n", foo.c) // no output because foo is not in the array (its address was not assign to the pointer 'p')

   return 0;
}
```

I would like to assign pointer `struct Test ***p` value of `foo`. So that I can manipulate with that pointer (declaring values in member of that struct). How to achieve this?

Comment: `// var 'p' is kind of type "struct Test ***p"` That's not true. `[]` and `*` are not freely interchangeable in all cases.

Comment: Considering that the structure is not "deep", it only have "shallow" data, what's bad with a shallow copy?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yeah, but almost. I know there are nuances, but I have not encounter any problem with interchange them yet. Not saying it could not happen.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wait, I will edit

Comment: The type of your `p` is `struct Test *(*)[10]`.  This is not the same as `struct Test ***`, nor are the two types compatible.  If you actually want a triple pointer (and, generally speaking, you shouldn't) then that's what you should declare.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would need some example, where interchanging one with another would cause error. just for ilustration

Comment: Moreover, neither `foo` itself nor its address, `&foo`, has type compatible with either of the other two types mentioned.  It's not clear what you hope to accomplish with all this, but you would be well advised to avoid playing games.

Comment: @Herdsman [Here's an example of changing an array to a pointer breaking things.](https://tio.run/##fZDNDoIwEITvfYoGowGiol5RX0Q5kNLSTbA1/UHE8OxYgQR6cW8z32Yyu2RXEtL3KxCksgXFZ20KkHt@RQiEwY8cRFhLKCL8QdgN4bnCcXM7HjJ8mbzfBC1VMtjOWgq6lOblUcMV9TiTVnkaao9raDxJayqWBoWSm6UhwBUYZJeiRfUwfkdT@02TDuCp3KksDNb67jLxsHHKohQnycj02H@MYayymofuT9KayMuO4/ZfbDvHalqy3FZGo67vvw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: *but almost* No, absolutely not. Not even close. If you want something close, try "but only at the top level". Your `[]` is not at the top level. So much for that idea.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. do not get it. Top level here means last pointer? which actually points to the structs? And if so, why is this required to interchange array with pointer, and not in "deeper" level?

Comment: Well, @Herdsman, interchanging those, by cast, for example, leads to strict aliasing violations when you access the pointed-to objects.  The resulting behavior is undefined, and this sort of thing tends to get you into trouble with your compiler.  As a practical matter, pointer arithmetic (and thus, the indexing operator, too) has different implications for pointers of those different types.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I hardly understand, it would be better to explain your statements in example(s) (for example that with compiler problem or violation) as an answer here. I am not that experienced to be able to imagine in real would you are saying. But thanks for that

Comment: Top level is very simple. "Variable x is an Array Of blah blah". This has "array of" at top level, and it could be compatible with a pointer. "Variable y is a blah blah of Array of blah blah". This does not have "array of" at the top level, and it cannot be compatible with a pointer.

Comment: What's wrong with the one Joseph provided, @Herdsman?  A full example doesn't fit in comments.  If you want one, then pose a separate question.  But actually, don't, because I am sure you can find it answered several times over elsewhere on SO already.

Comment: @John Bollinger  can you please elaborate your statement `pointer arithmetic (indexing) has different implications for pointers of those different types`, What implication do you mean? That indexing is by bigger size of that pointed object? Please explain this `implication` with relation to compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call `malloc`, `ar[1]` (and by extension `p[0][1]`) points to an array of 2 *instances* of `struct Test`.  So `ar[1][0]` and `ar[1][1]` are both struct instances.

It seems like what you want is for them to be pointers so they can point to `foo`.  So you need an extra level of indirection:

```
struct Test **ar[10];
struct Test **(*p)[10] = &ar;

// allocate space at p[0][1] for 2 struct pointers
*(*p+1) = malloc(sizeof(struct Test *)*2); 

p[0][1][1] = &foo;
p[0][1][1]->c = 'c';
printf("%c\n", foo.c);
```

Comment: But I though, I do not have to add indirection. Well `*(*ar+1)` is an array (or pointer), and I thought, I could assign it an address. But you are right, I need another indirection

Comment: @Herdsman It *is* a pointer, but you assign the address of an array of struct instances there.  If you only want one instance you can assign `&foo` to that directly without allocating anything.